# Using a local HTML file too trigger a bash script execution

Tags: linux, bash, html

While this question seems like its asking for code, its not; *exactly*, which is why its here instead of SO.

I'm designing a RPG game in bash, a lot of things that an RPG game would need, fixed displays, and etc. Worked in HTML, so I thought "Why not use a text based web browser too parse and display the HTML files" I looked into links, lynx, w3m, and elinks. But I couldn't find a way too have the web browser take a HTML button, trigger a bash based script too run.

Is this too advanced? Or is there some other way if doing this without requiring a online aspect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.5/lynx2-8-5/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html)'s user guide:

> Local execution scripts or links
>   Local execution is activated when Lynx is first set up.
>
> If it has not been activated you will not see this option in the Options Menu.
>
> When a local execution script is encountered Lynx checks the users options to see whether the script can be executed. Users have the following options:
>
> If the users options permit the script to be executed Lynx will spawn a shell and run the script.
>
> If the script cannot be executed Lynx will show the script within the Lynx window and inform the user that the script is not allowed to be executed and will ask the user to check his/her options

Answer (score 1):

You must use some script to do this. Client side script VBS should be able to do it as well as server side preprocessor like PHP (see exec() or system() functions)

Comment: The thing is, I want too __avoid__ serverside, as the program is _entiely_ clientside, all of it. It's a local HTML file, not transmitted over the WWW.

Comment: yes serverside would mean that you would have to install apache server  and PHP into your computer ;) Or just use this visual basic script and it will work without installing server software I believe

Comment: I suppose that could be done.

Comment: if you consider installing server software, I suggest XAMPP. Very simple to setup

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out, I used too use WAMP, but I'll give that a shot